# Jenkins Promotion Parameter values not coming through in Shell Exec Command

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I have created build promotion "choice" parameter named "RUNSCRIPT" with values "No" (as default) and "Yes" and trying to get the value of parameter in EXEC SHELL command as $RUNSCRIPT but neither value "Yes" or "No" coming through. If I look at the output it comes as $RUNSCRIPT (as it is). Why is not being replaced with value. Any suggestions? Also, tried to create other type of parameters e.g. String value but its not working as well.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) article will be helpful.

Comment: Thats is for Build Parameter which is different from Promotion Parameter.

Comment: Are these parameters called "Approval Parameters"? If so, they do work and expand in the promotion actions for me. Maybe you could post your configuration files somewhere, like pastebin or gist.

Comment: Well, they are Approval parameters in promotion Action. Also, another action in same promotion is "Send build artifacts over SSH" that has "Exec command" file where you mention shell command. I am trying to get its value from there as $RUNSCRIPT also tried £{RUNSCRIPT} and %RUNSCRIPT but nothing working. How is it working for you what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a value from jenkins to a script you need to define the parameter as jenkins environment variable. I have used Ant for this. For example :

property environment="env"
property name="user" value="${env.user}"

if I just use

property name="user" value="${user}"

the values will be passed from some other file that is referring user.

Comment: But, I thought that should do it for you as you create parameter on promotion because if you see help it says: "These parameters are exposed to build as environment variables.". Anyway, how/where would you create that environment variable in Jenkins please?

Comment: Are you using promotion plugin

Comment: Yes. We are using promotion plugin.

Comment: I have never used that plugin, but you can use ant like explained above for such operations. I have also notied that there is a bug in thus parameter may be this URL might help you.  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5679

Comment: That bug is something else not related to this.

Comment: while declaring a node you can define the Environment Variables for that particular node.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get an Approval Parameter to be passed as a Build Parameter on a downstream build (triggered by the promotion itself); you simply need to pass them on.

I learned that Approval parameters are allowed within the approval "build" so to speak, so any actions you have in that approval should be able to reference any of the Approval parameters.

This means you can have an approval parameter FOO, and then in the approval actions, if you have a "Trigger parameterized build" action, you can use a "Predefined parameters" with the text:

```
 BAR=${FOO}
```

The triggered build will then have the BAR build proprerty set with the value of whatever the build was promoted with.